# Debug Emacs Lisp major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm developing a major mode for Emacs.  Is there any way that I can set a break point in the source code when fontification happens, for example?

Answer (score 7):

Find the Lisp source of the function you'd like to step through, and type `M-x edebug-defun` there.  Then, whenever that function is executed, you'll automatically be placed into Edebug, where you can step through it if you wish.

Fontification functions can be a bit tricky though, as they can be invoked at odd times.  You can use the `message` function to write messages into the `*Messages*` buffer.  Another trick is to turn off Font Lock (so your function doesn't get invoked automatically), then prep the function you're debugging with `edebug-defun` and invoke it manually.  (Note that you can use `M-:` (a.k.a. `eval-expression`) to invoke a non-interactive function.)

Comment: Yes, this works for my indent-region function, but, as you warn, not for the fontification function!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The manual for debugging elisp can be [found here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Debugging.html#Debugging).

You can used `edebug` as mentioned, there's also <kbd>M-x debug-on-entry</kbd> and you can set `(setq debug-on-quit t)`.  Check out all the options in the link, it all depends on how you want to skin the cat.

Answer (score 1):

And just like in any other programming language, you can debug with print statements.  `(message "here, foo=%d" foo)` is your friend.  (You probably know that these messages are accumulated in the `*Messages*` buffer, so if they go by too quickly, that's not a problem.)  `trace-function` is also helpful.

I have written a lot of emacs modes and have only rarely needed the debugger.  Usually the problem exposes itself with a few well-placed print statements.

Comment: In principle, a debugger is just a glorified 'insert-print-statement' machine but it automates the task for you, while not spoiling the code itself.  And I would find that functionality useful for debugging the elisp function I am writing, especially as I am fairly new to elisp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `edebug` you can use `debug`.  To open the debugger on entry to a function, use `M-x debug-on-entry THE-FUNCTION`.  Or insert calls to function `debug` in the source code to serve as breakpoints (re-eval the code).

However, fontification actually takes place at odd times, involving redisplay etc.  If you really need to debug the fontification process, then you can use functions, not just regexps, in `font-lock-keywords`.

But really you will need to be more specific about your font-lock debugging problems. Typically the problems people have are (a) understanding `font-lock-keywords` (the structure) and (b) regexps that don't match what they want.

Anyway, to answer your question about *breakpoints": Yes, just insert `(debug)` at any point you want in the Lisp source code. The debugger will be entered at that point.

Answer (score 0):

On an another note as well if you want to just quickly debug some lisp snippet you maybe want to use the ielm mode as well which works like for example the python interactive mode.